# Enable/disable USB devices on Windows using Active Directory on certain users

Tags: windows, security, active-directory, usb

I have been asked to disable access to USB devices on Windows machines for information disclosure reasons.

Although this can be done with Active Directory, the problem is that the solution should let us enable access for certain users for limited authorised periods.

How can this be done with Active Directory (if it's possible)?

If not, which software can I use to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about a setting that gets applied to computers, not to users. If you don't mind applying it to computers, you could create a security group and place the computers into it which aren't supposed to be "restricted". Modify the permissions of the Group Policy Object in which you're applying these restrictions to include "Deny Apply Group Policy" for the computer group you've created and the settings won't apply to those computers anymore. You can move computers in and out of the group as-necessary, but I'm fairly certain you'd be stuck rebooting the computers to get a change in restriction versus non-restriction to take effect.

Comment: Rebooting doesn't seem to be a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I hear, epoxy is a very popular solution to this problem.

[How do you prevent users from using USB drives which circumvent security](https://serverfault.com/questions/28276/how-do-you-prevent-users-from-using-usb-drives-which-circumvent-security)

[physical port locks for ethernet, USB, phone, etc.?](https://serverfault.com/questions/16279/physical-port-locks-for-ethernet-usb-phone-etc)

Really, though, the GP looks like the best answer:

http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2005/11/15/disabling-usb-storage-with-group-policy.html

Answer (score 0):

I setup a ADM in my last company and set the GP to certain groups.  Enabled Mass Storage and Disable Mass Storage.  They required reboot if there groups changed.  Its a registry change to basically disable the USB mass storage driver.

Here is the ADM I used.  Grabbed it from Google years ago.

```
CLASS MACHINE
CATEGORY !!category
 CATEGORY !!categoryname
  POLICY !!policynameusb
   KEYNAME "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR"
   EXPLAIN !!explaintextusb
     PART !!labeltextusb DROPDOWNLIST REQUIRED

       VALUENAME "Start"
       ITEMLIST
        NAME !!Disabled VALUE NUMERIC 3 DEFAULT
        NAME !!Enabled VALUE NUMERIC 4
       END ITEMLIST
     END PART
   END POLICY
  POLICY !!policynamecd
   KEYNAME "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Cdrom"
   EXPLAIN !!explaintextcd
     PART !!labeltextcd DROPDOWNLIST REQUIRED

       VALUENAME "Start"
       ITEMLIST
        NAME !!Disabled VALUE NUMERIC 1 DEFAULT
        NAME !!Enabled VALUE NUMERIC 4
       END ITEMLIST
     END PART
   END POLICY
  POLICY !!policynameflpy
   KEYNAME "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Flpydisk"
   EXPLAIN !!explaintextflpy
     PART !!labeltextflpy DROPDOWNLIST REQUIRED

       VALUENAME "Start"
       ITEMLIST
        NAME !!Disabled VALUE NUMERIC 3 DEFAULT
        NAME !!Enabled VALUE NUMERIC 4
       END ITEMLIST
     END PART
   END POLICY
  POLICY !!policynamels120
   KEYNAME "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Sfloppy"
   EXPLAIN !!explaintextls120
     PART !!labeltextls120 DROPDOWNLIST REQUIRED

       VALUENAME "Start"
       ITEMLIST
        NAME !!Disabled VALUE NUMERIC 3 DEFAULT
        NAME !!Enabled VALUE NUMERIC 4
       END ITEMLIST
     END PART
   END POLICY
 END CATEGORY
END CATEGORY

[strings]
category="Custom Policy Settings"
categoryname="Restrict Drives"
policynameusb="Disable USB Removable Drives"
policynamecd="Disable CD-ROM"
policynameflpy="Disable Floppy"
policynamels120="Disable High Capacity Floppy"
explaintextusb="Disables the USB Removable Drives capability by disabling the usbstor.sys driver. \n\nSelect the ENABLED radiobox, then select STOPPED for the usbstore.sys driver status in the drop-down list.  \n\nNote that this will only prevent usage of newly plugged-in USB Removable Drives or Flash Drives, devices that were plugged-in while this option was not configured will continue to function normally. Also, devices that use the same device or hardware ID (for example - 2 identical Flash Disks made by the same manufacturer) will still function if one of them was plugged-in prior to the configuration of this setting. In order to successfully block them you will need to make sure no USB Removable Drive is plugged-in while you set this option. \n\nIn order to re-enable the usage of USB Removable Drives select STARTED for the usbstore.sys driver status in the drop-down list."
explaintextcd="Disables the CD-ROM Drive by disabling the cdrom.sys driver. \n\nSelect the ENABLED radiobox, then select STOPPED for the cdrom.sys driver status in the drop-down list. \n\nIn order to re-enable the usage of USB Removable Drives select STARTED for the cdrom.sys driver status in the drop-down list."
explaintextflpy="Disables the Floppy Drive by disabling the flpydisk.sys driver. \n\nSelect the ENABLED radiobox, then select STOPPED for the flpydisk.sys driver status in the drop-down list. \n\nIn order to re-enable the usage of USB Removable Drives select STARTED for the flpydisk.sys driver status in the drop-down list."
explaintextls120="Disables the High Capacity Floppy Drive by disabling the sfloppy.sys driver. \n\nSelect the ENABLED radiobox, then select STOPPED for the sfloppy.sys driver status in the drop-down list. \n\nIn order to re-enable the usage of USB Removable Drives select STARTED for the sfloppy.sys driver status in the drop-down list."
labeltextusb="usbstore.sys driver status"
labeltextcd="cdrom.sys driver status"
labeltextflpy="flpydisk.sys driver status"
labeltextls120="sfloppy.sys driver status"
Enabled="Stopped"
Disabled="Started"
```

Answer (score 0):

If disabled USB mass storage device using gpedit in windows7

1. Reset the gpedit configuration
   Set All removable storage classes : deny all access to not configured
2. Then Gpupdate
3. Driver installation
   Device manager -> update driver -> browse : c -> windows ->inf-> usbsstore.disabled 
   (rename usbstore.disabled to usbstore.inf then select usbstore.inf) -> next
   Finish
4. Restart the machine